# What is the origin of the stereotype that Polish people lack intelligence?

Tags: united-states, cultural-history, poland, ethnicity

A quick glance at Wikipedia's [list of Polish people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Polish_people) demonstrates the stereotype as false.  Poland has produced notable minds in such diverse areas of knowledge as Astronomy (Nicolaus Copernicus), Chemistry (Marie Curie), Music (Frédéric Chopin and Henryk Górecki), Literature (Stanisław Lem), Religion (Karol Józef Wojtyla AKA Pope John Paul II), and Politics (Lech Wałęsa). A deeper look into that list reveals a number of highly intelligent Polish people who are less well known.

Yet, there are an innumerable jokes and unfair stereotypes regarding Polish people being of inferior intelligence in American culture.

**Where did this stereotype originate?**

Comment: @stevvve - Polish is pretty much a US thing, in the UK it's the Irish, in France the Belgians.

Comment: Let's be honest - the source of **any** such stereotype is simple bigotry - and close this question as a matter of **totally uninformed** opinion.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens wrong: some stereotypes still have strong roots in reality, if distorted. For instance "greedy jews" is a stereotype, but jews have managed money and gold for centuries, so that stereotype isn't "just random". Of course it may be wrong and insulting, but hiding under the sand and pretending it doesn't exist isn't exactly a good idea.

Comment: Note: there is a [meta discussion concerning this question](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/837/why-is-this-bigotry-tolerated-on-the-site).

Comment: As much as I'm unfortunately late for the party, I want to express my gratitude for asking this question. It resulted in answers on a matter that I as a Pole was also curious about. From time to time it's me who's asked by people of other nationalities - why does such a stereotype exist, and usually I just shrug my arms, not knowing what to answer (except for the obvious "they just needed somebody to play the role of the dumb one").

Comment: With respect to Nicolaus Copernicus, Germans and Polish still argue occasionally about whether he was German or Polish. The issue doesn't seem to have a definite answer as of yet.

Comment: The history section of the Wikipedia article on [Polish jokes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_joke) is a pretty reasonable answer.

Comment: @o0'., and, of course, since Christians were not allowed to charge interest on loans for several centuries, and since Jews were not allowed (by Christians) to hold many other jobs, the Christian world created "Jewish bankers". :)

Comment: Is this question really necessary on the History Stack Exchange?  This question should be closed, due to its inappropriateness.

Comment: @Alex this is still history, even if you don't like it. Closing it would be inappropriate.

Comment: You're absolutely right, "this is still history", which is why I "still" believe that this question should be closed...it is, an unnecessary question.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Personally, I suspect this is mostly an American (USA) stereotype, which chiefly originates from a couple of factors.

1. We had a couple of [large waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Poles_in_the_United_States#Wave_of_Polish_immigration) of East European immigration in the nineteenth and early twentieth centuries, which brought large numbers of Poles who knew little or no English. As human beings, we tend to perceive those who have trouble expressing themselves in our own language as possessing substandard intelligence. This is particularly a problem with Americans, as the vast majority of us don't know any language besides English, so the roles are never reversed for us. The exemplar here is Psychology professor [Carl Brigham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Brigham), who in 1923 published a very influential study that made this exact mistake (using English aptitude tests on immigrants to measure intelligence).
2. Immigrants of the era tended to enter at the lowest stratum of society. Polish immigrants were no exception, and in fact tended to get work primarily in menial jobs that even other [immigrant groups avoided](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Poles_in_the_United_States#Fields_of_work). Anti-Catholic prejudice of the era tended to act to keep Polish families there for an extra generation or two. It's fairly common to believe that those socially below you are of lesser intelligence than yourself. (If you don't believe that, you might start to believe that you don't inherently deserve your own lofty status. Not a pleasant line of thought there.)

Comment: How would only knowing one language make a person *less* likely to experience the situation of being unable to express themselves?

Comment: @Joe - In an extremely monoligual society, it pretty much ensures it.

Comment: "the roles are never reversed for us" - Not back then but now there are areas you can go to a be at a significant disadvantage if you don't speak Spanish.

Comment: I think part of the first point T.E.D. notes comes from the latter part of the 18th Century when Social Darwinism was in place, as well as much anti-immigrant fever from "non-acceptable" areas in Europe (read central or the UK).  Eastern Europeans were already coming into a society with an influx of immigrants who were already looked down upon, the Italians and Irish were already feeling this, so it was just an extension of existing cultural attitudes.  The language barrier was also a factor as well, as noted.

Comment: @jfrankcarr - Quite. This is a point I try to make to my kids when they are picking which language to study in school. I have trouble communicating with half my soccer team now.

Comment: Of course, it is not only American stereotype. Similar stereotypes about Poles exist also in Germany and Russia.

Comment: @jfrankcarr No, then you just say speak English, but SLOWER AND LOUDER. You have to actively try to learn a language to realize how stupid it makes you look.

Comment: @Anixx I'd argue that the origins of the stereotype for USA and for the neighboring countries are totally different. It's a common thing to think of your neighbors like that, not only in the history of nations, but in all history of society - how many people think "I'm smarter than my neighbor and my cat is smarter than his dog".

Comment: Well, the ignorant Irish were starting to do well.  Somebody had to replace them.

Comment: This answer doesn't make much sense, since the vast majority of immigrants to the US have come speaking little english, and are more often than not poor.  But yet they had different stereotypes associated with them.  I think the Nazi answer below makes much more sense, and incorporates facts and connects Polish stereotypes with other parts of history.

Answer (score 22):

Derogatory racial (for lack of a better word) stereotypes tell much about the people who spread them.
For instance, in my field - software development, you are not likely to come across "Polish jokes", because some of the best developers in top tech firms are Polish and Polish universities regularly outperform US teams in international programming contests. If you hear such jokes at work then it probably means that you aren't working in a cutting edge technology corporation.

That being said, I like the answer given by TED, because it explains the issue in terms of a self defence mechanism of a society which experiences mass immigration. I would like to add to this though as there are additional factors at play, all revolving around the image of Poles and Poland in the US, which shed some light on why the derogatory stereotypes haven't died so far.

I think much of the problem boils down to the fact that Poles as immigrants have been an easy target.

I think a large part of the people who tell Polish or Irish jokes would like to make derogatory comments about "blacks" or Jews. But with the level of protection those groups enjoy in a modern state, it's hardly possible. Polish look, on the other hand, is not much different from the Anglo-Saxon one (which traditionally has been the look of the US establishment) and their culture is also quite similar. Thus Poles don't deserve protection in the eyes of the anti-racist lobby.

The observation of what recently happened in the UK seems to corroborate this theory. After 2004 UK experienced mass Polish immigration. This time there was no "dumb Polacks" stereotype, but the attacks aimed at Polish immigrants were frequent - from typical ("Poles take our jobs and send all the money home") to very ridiculous ones ("Poles hunt for swans in public parks") and even physical attacks. The interesting thing though is that at the same time UK has been dealing with a very large immigration from Africa and Asia. Under other circumstances those immigrants would be the primary target of discrimination as they were more culturally alien than the Poles (not to mention the very different physical appearance). But that never happened as the political culture of the UK would result in the immediate stigmatisation of the attacker. Instead, the suppressed anger was directed at "Eastern Europeans", without consequences.

Secondly, at the time of the mass Polish emigration to Americas there was no Polish state. Poles were second class citizens of Germany, Russia and Austria. It is hard to be proud of your nationality when your country has been conquered. And it is common not to respect a nation that has failed. Nations that  are likely to be respected are nations that have demonstrated their strength via powerful statehood. I think the Irish experienced that too.

Thirdly, Polish emigration to USA, Brazil and Argentina was mostly economical. They were mostly impoverished peasant. The wealthy and politically active Polish intelligentsia stayed in Europe. So it took time before the US Polonia could produce leaders able to represent their interest within the US.

The final blow came when Poland got into Soviet sphere of influence after WWII. For over 50 years there was no Polish ambassador which could defend Polish American while acting as a representative of a US-friendly state. Quite the contrary, as a Warsaw pact member, Poland became de facto an enemy of the US. If Cold War was to escalate into WWIII, American troops in Europe would likely face Polish People's Republic troops. American media of that period must have taken note of that.
Another aspect is that USA was a strongly pro capitalist country and as such it promoted the image of communist economy as inferior. So the news coverage from Poland for a very long time stressed the backwardness of the Polish economy. This message was so strong that to this very day people in the USA have an image of Poland that is very removed from reality.

Paradoxically, Poland and Poles had already been deliberately negatively depicted in the US during WWII, while being an ally of the USA! This has been well documented and explained in the book "[Hollywood's War with Poland, 1939-1945](http://cosmopolitanreview.com/hollywoods-war-with-poland/)".
To cut a story short, it takes some bad luck to be negatively portrayed twice: first because of being anti-Soviet and later because of being pro-Soviet. That's what happened to Poland though.

There is also one, often overlooked, factor that I personally think had a big impact on Polish image in the USA - the never ending Polish - Jewish conflict. It's too complex to even attempt to describe it here - the important thing though is that media have become a weapon in this conflict and so Poles were doomed to lose it, since Poles didn't engage in media at similar frequency as the Jews. This has resulted in some polonophobic ideas leaking into popular American culture, as described in the book "[Bieganski: The Brute Polak Stereotype in Polish-Jewish Relations and American Popular Culture](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1936235153)".

(In contrast, I think it was the long lasting media involvement that was the primary factor which catapulted the Jewish minority into upper echelons of American establishment. Which is ironic because the bulk of Jewish immigrants came to the USA from the territories of former Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth and so they too were often called "dumb Polacks" upon landing on American soil.)

Finally, Polish Americans have not been numerous and influential enough to be a force to be reckoned with for politicians. A presidential candidate won't put up a Polish American as vice president just for the sake of securing votes of that minority, since there are more numerous groups to appease.

Last but not least, Polish language is extremely difficult for a foreigner. Learning it requires much more time and dedication than for example Italian or Spanish. That's a barrier that very few people are ready to overcome, so Polish culture and literature is little known. This leaves space to assume that it is somehow inferior.

Comment: Ironically the same C20th circumstances gave the opposite stereotype in Britain. Poland was the brave little country that fought the Nazis and then the USSR. When a British far-right party used an image of a Spitfire in a campaign and it turned out to actually be a Free Polish Airforce ace, they lost all their support by implying that attacking the role of Poland in WWII was in any way "British".

Answer (score 7):

The origin of the stereotype that Polish people have inferior intelligence came from Nazi German propaganda that ironically NBC-TV/Hollywood introduced into the US in the 196O's (despite NBC-TV claiming to be against the Nazis) in many of its TV shows like the "Tonight Show" and any other show where the word "Polish" would be mentioned and maligned.    NBC-TV's George Schlatter bashed Polish people a lot in his show "Laugh-In" which ridiculed Polish people with subhuman intelligence jokes.

The Polish American Guardian Society, The Polish American "Post Eagle" newspaper and the Polish American Congress Anti-Bigotry committee hold Anti-Polish TV Bigots mostly responsible for using the power of TV to malign the image of Polish people.

[Chet Grabowski](http://www.northjersey.com/news/opinions/150122865_End_of_an_era_with_death_of_Chester_Grabowski.html), the editor of the "Post Eagle", was credited with much of the decline in so called "Polish jokes" from mainstream TV media, according to the Polish American Singer Bobby Vinton.

Comment: Welcome to History.SE. I think you provided an interesting perspective. Also thanks for providing a source for Chet Grabowski. Are there any other sources in regards to the first section of the answer? If you could provide a few more sources I would give +1 (currently all votes cast till tomorrow)

Comment: Agree with E1Suave on sources. IMHO the logic here fails Hanlon's Razor, so I'd really like to see where it came from.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer, and should be upvoted more.Wikipedia seems to agree about the Nazi sterotypes of low IQ.

Answer (score 5):

Mostly good old fashioned racism. The target is different for different cultures (Polish people in USA, Irish people in UK, etc.), but the general idea is to insult the people you don't like.

Answer (score 2):

It's common for nearby groups to have jokes told about them, from gentle ribbing going on to more serious X-ism, where X is race, or national, or whatever.  Inside the US, there are jokes about Texans, New Englanders, Vermonters.  Ohio has jokes about neighboring Kentucky.  I imagine that most nations have the same thing with countries alongside.

Since there was a large amount of US immmigration from Germany in the 1800s, followed by a lesser, later influx from Poland, that the US has taken on a bit of the German attitude towards their neighbors to the East.

Answer (score 2):

Facts seem to show so-called Polish jokes are mainly Jewish American gags about (imagined) Poles. For example, books by a Jewish "comic" Larry Wilde, gags in Hollywood films e.g. by Allen. The extreme vulgarity, including frequent references to feces, and contempt towards the Poles makes these "jokes" a case of hate propaganda against a national group.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back up the statements in your answer?

Comment: Before making answers such as this with such strong claims on questions with acceptable answers, I would recommend having at least two sources for such statements.

Comment: There were a lot of Jewish comics, some of whom were descendants of immigrants from Poland. This could have resulted in a lot of Polish jokes. I bet Poles even today have some Jewish jokes.

Answer (score 2):

I have also read that the denigration of Poles was a deliberate tactic of Stalin's wartime propaganda in order to blunt the western reaction to his planned takeover of Poland after the war. He didn't want the western people to realize how much Poland actually contributed to the war effort against the Nazis. Polish units fought in North Africa and Italy. Polish airmen made up a significant percentage of pilots who fought in the Battle of Britain. France surrendered but was always part of the meetings at Yalta, etc. Poland never surrendered but was excluded at Stalin's insistence.

Comment: Sources please.

Answer (score 0):

I believe many ethnic groups were felt to be inferior mentally by immigration officials in the late 19th and early 20th centuries. This included not just Poles but also Jews and Italians. Gould wrote a book about the silly "intelligence" tests given immigrants which asked questions about baseball, etc.

If you feel that somehow even now this belief is widely held about Poles, it could stem simply from the "Polish Joke" which followed a certain pattern. These I don't think are very popular anymore. Similar jokes were told about blonde women a generation or two later.

Answer (score 0):

I was told by a polish woman this term came from the fact that Nazi's would come to people's (non-Jewish) homes of high stature and education, tell them they had a choice of siding with the Germans or not. If not, they were murdered. Most being proud Pols chose the latter.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the connection of this answer to the question that was posed.

Answer (score -1):

Around 35 years ago some of my elderly Jewish relatives got to wondering how jokes about Polish people being stupid got started. One of the people present was an elderly Polish Catholic woman who had married a Polish Jewish man (my relative by marriage).  I have to say, that this elderly Polish Catholic woman was the only "stupid" Polish person I've ever met. Every other person I've known to be Polish (usually because they've immigrated to this country since WWII) was very bright.  Honestly, I don't really know if this elderly Polish lady was really stupid.  Perhaps she just had the brains to keep her mouth shut unless she agreed with what was being said.  She also had basically no education (so if she had been bright in math, who would know?)  She couldn't have been entirely stupid, as she stayed happily married her whole life and with lots of children who loved her.

Anyway, the conclusion reached by the group (which she chimed in and agreed to) is that the reason Polish people were thought of as stupid in America is because so many Polish Jews had moved to America, and due to Polish antisemitism, Jews had developed lots of jokes about how stupid Polish people were and easy to fool (so as to make themselves feel less afraid while being the minority still living in Poland).

Comment: I'm not sure that the first section is particularly useful. You refer this old lady as 'stupid' and then present evidence that suggests she was merely uneducated, either way it has little to do with an answer to the question.